# How does this mapper pattern work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found RailsCasts [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3), and used this logic and code samples for my needs.

But one thing bothers me.

constraint looks like:

```
 constraints(Subdomain.new) do ... end
```

which uses this code:

```
class Subdomain
  def matches?(request)
    ....
    end
  end
end
```

And it works.

But I don't get two things. First, I do not invoke `matches?` anywhere, why this method is just executed on initializing `Subdomain.new`?

Second concern. I don't pass any parameter, but it somehow assigns `request` argument to actual rack request and it just works.

For example, I didn't like this syntax:

```
constraints(Subdomain.new) do ... end
```

so I decided to make it module with method `subdomain(request)`, but as made it module, it started raising wrong number or arguments error (0 for 1).

I found out that method `matches?` is defined in `mapper.rb`, may be it is called somewhere backwards in rails, but this way it should be overwritten by my subdomain file? If not, as my `matches` is class method, how it works without any Subdomain instance to which it is applied?

As I said, everything works fine, but I would like to understand what exactly happens, because I don't like using something that appears david blane magic code to me.

Reading some source code of Rails mapper module didn't give me understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Well, little more of reading source code gave me a clue. I found one more `matches?`, defined for `@constraints`

```
 def matches?(req)
          @constraints.all? do |constraint|
            (constraint.respond_to?(:matches?) && constraint.matches?(req)) ||
              (constraint.respond_to?(:call) && constraint.call(*constraint_args(constraint, req)))
          end
        end
```

So for every constraint it checks if it responds to `matches?` and then invokes it with rack request argument.

Comment: reason for downvoting, may be?